# Image with slide out panel description

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I have the below code where the description box slides out when you hover over the image. I'm trying to change it for my requirements so that when you move mouse away the description box disappears instead of sliding back underneath image. Can someone suggest where I need to make this change and what css I should add/insert?
Thanks in advance

```css
<style>

.imagepluscontainer{ /* main image container */
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}

.imagepluscontainer img{ /* CSS for image within container */
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* Enable CSS3 transition on all props */
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.imagepluscontainer:hover img{ /* CSS for image when mouse hovers over main container */
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-moz-transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
-ms-transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
-o-transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
}

.imagepluscontainer div.desc{ /* CSS for desc div of each image. */
position: absolute;
width: 90%;
z-index: 1; /* Set z-index to that less than image's, so it's hidden beneath it */
bottom: 0; /* Default position of desc div is bottom of container, setting it up to slide down */
left: 5px;
padding: 8px;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); /* black bg with 80% opacity */
color: white;
-moz-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px; /* CSS3 rounded borders */
-webkit-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
opacity: 0; /* Set initial opacity to 0 */
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); /* CSS3 shadows */
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s; /* Enable CSS3 transition on desc div. Final 0.5s value is the delay before animation starts */
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
}

.imagepluscontainer div.desc a{
color: white;
}

.imagepluscontainer:hover div.desc{ /* CSS for desc div when mouse hovers over main container */
-moz-transform: translate(0, 100%);
-webkit-transform: translate(0, 100%);
-ms-transform: translate(0, 100%);
-o-transform: translate(0, 100%);
transform: translate(0, 100%);
opacity:1; /* Reveal desc DIV fully */
}

/*### Below CSS when applied to desc DIV slides the desc div from the right edge of the image ###*/

.imagepluscontainer div.rightslide{
width: 150px; /* reset from default */
top:15px;
right:0;
left:auto;  /* reset from default */
bottom:auto;  /* reset from default */
padding-left:15px;
-moz-border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
}

.imagepluscontainer:hover div.rightslide{
-moz-transform: translate(100%, 0);
-webkit-transform: translate(100%, 0);
-ms-transform: translate(100%, 0);
-o-transform: translate(100%, 0);
transform: translate(100%, 0);
}

/*### Below CSS when applied to desc DIV slides the desc div from the left edge of the image ###*/

.imagepluscontainer div.leftslide{
width: 150px;  /* reset from default */
top:15px;
left:0;
bottom:auto;  /* reset from default */
padding-left:15px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
}

.imagepluscontainer:hover div.leftslide{
-moz-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
-webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
-ms-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
-o-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
transform:translate(-100%, 0);
}

/*### Below CSS when applied to desc DIV slides the desc div from the top edge of the image ###*/

.imagepluscontainer div.upslide{
top:0;
bottom:auto;  /* reset from default */
padding-bottom:10px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
}

.imagepluscontainer:hover div.upslide{
-moz-transform: translate(0, -100%);
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -100%);
-ms-transform: translate(0, -100%);
-o-transform: translate(0, -100%);
transform:translate(0, -100%);
}

</style>
```

```html
<!-- Make sure each container contains explicit width/height attrs that reflect the dimensions of the showcased image-->

<div class="imagepluscontainer" style="width:263px; height:199px; z-index:2">
<img src="http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/4546/stadiumij.jpg" />
<div class="desc">
Capable of seating 50,000 spectators, the <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colosseum">Colosseum</a> was used for gladiatorial contests and public spectacles such as executions.
</div>
</div>

<br />

<div class="imagepluscontainer" style="width:263px; height:199px; left:350px">
<img src="http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/4546/stadiumij.jpg" />
<div class="desc rightslide">
Capable of seating 50,000 spectators, the <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colosseum">Colosseum</a> was used for gladiatorial contests and public spectacles such as executions.
</div>
</div>

<br />

<div class="imagepluscontainer" style="width:263px; height:199px">
<img src="http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/4546/stadiumij.jpg" />
<div class="desc upslide">
Capable of seating 50,000 spectators, the <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colosseum">Colosseum</a> was used for gladiatorial contests and public spectacles such as executions.
</div>
</div>

<br />

<div class="imagepluscontainer" style="width:263px; height:199px; left:350px">
<img src="http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/4546/stadiumij.jpg" />
<div class="desc leftslide">
Capable of seating 50,000 spectators, the <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colosseum">Colosseum</a> was used for gladiatorial contests and public spectacles such as executions.
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the difference between "disappears" and "sliding back underneath the image"?

Comment: At the moment the description slides back in. When an image is hovered  the description box slides out either left, right, top or bottom and then reverses back in. So, what I am after is to stop the reverse back in.. but instead vanish/disappear?

Comment: In general, you'll have to set either the display or opacity property for the description divs, then reverse that *before* the slide out (so you can see it slide out on another image) What have you attempted? Where are you running into trouble?